# Deep watch in not working on object Vue

Tags: javascript, oop, vue.js

I have a watcher setup on an array and I have deep watch enabled on it, however the handler function does not trigger when the array changes, applications is defined in the object returned in data. Here's the code:

```
  watch: {
    applications: {
      handler: function(val, oldVal) {
        console.log('app changed');
      },
      deep: true,
    },
    page(newPage) {
      console.log('Newpage', newPage);
    },
  },
```

Comment: show how the array is changed.

Comment: For example the array goes from [] to [[1, 2, 3]] after an async call in the mounted hook. And I know this is the case because I can see the array has changed through the Vue chrome devtool

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Vue cannot detect some changes to an array such as when you directly set an item within the index:

> e.g. arr[indexOfItem] = newValue

Here are some alternative ways to detect changes in an array:

```
Vue.set(arr, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

or

```
arr.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

You can find better understanding of Array Change Detection [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

Comment: And `Vue.delete(object, key)` instead of `Vue.set(object, key, undefined)`

Answer (score 2):

If you reset your array with `arr[ index ] = 'some value'`, Vue doesn't track to this variable. It would better to use [Vue array’s mutation method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection). These methods used to track array change detection by Vue.

It is worked for me.